# Unable to declare string property defaults

Tags: delphi, properties, components, default-value

I'm writing a component which consists of many properties which are to appear in the Delphi IDE Object Inspector (published properties)...

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyProperty: String;
  published
    property MyProperty: String read FMyProperty write SetMyProperty default 'Something';
  end;
```

However, it's not allowing me to apply a default value to a string property...

```
[DCC Error] MyUnit.pas(278): E2146 Default values must be of ordinal, pointer or small set type
```

All other property defaults work fine (Integer, Enum, etc.).

My goal is to A) not save string properties to the DFM if they're the default value, and B) show the value in the Object Inspector as **Bold** if it's not the default, and regular if it is. There are over 130 properties which show for this component, and about 50 of them are string properties, some with rather large default values.

Why am I not allowed to declare a string property with a default value? Is this a shortcoming with Delphi, or is there a technical reason why strings can't be defaulted?

**EDIT**

If you really want to know what I'm doing, I'm encapsulating Inno Setup and wrapping the functionality into a component with an extensive property/collection editor. This topic pertains to just the `Setup` section alone, which consists of actually over 100 properties. Only about 20 of these properties are expected to actually be used for simple implementation, and therefore I don't want all the rest of those string properties to bloat the size of the DFM (if they're set to their defaults). Based on how the component is set up, it will produce an Inno Setup script file.

Comment: Uhm, because the compiler doesn't support it ?

Comment: @TLama I see that, but why? Strings are so common, why would the compiler skip such a common type as a `string`?

Comment: That's the question merely targeted to the compiler designers. Personally I don't see anything preventing implementation of all the types from my point of view. In a similar manner you can ask, why the values given by the `default` specifiers are not used to initialize property values.

Comment: @TLama I am initializing all the defaults (of over 100 properties) in the constructor. That wasn't relevant to the question though, so I didn't include it.

Comment: But back to your problem. Simply make a `stored` directive method which will return False when the property field will equal to the default value. ...as Remy shown in his answer...

Comment: For the record, Inno Setup's `Setup` section consists of 132 possible properties, with a few of my own so about 135 properties (Honestly actually in a `TPersistent` rather than a `TComponent`). 53 of those properties are `string` values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only numeric properties can have a `default` value specified in the property declaration.  However, you can use the `stored` specifier instead, eg:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyProperty: String;
    function MyPropertyIsStored: Boolean;
    procedure SetMyProperty(const Value: String);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property MyProperty: String read FMyProperty write SetMyProperty stored MyPropertyIsStored;
end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited;
  FMyProperty := 'my default value';
end;

function TMyComponent.MyPropertyIsStored: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FMyProperty <> 'my default value';
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyProperty(const Value: String);
begin
  if FMyProperty <> Value then
  begin
    FMyProperty := Value;
    // update component as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1. I was editing to add the docs on default (and about to add stored) when I saw a new answer had been posted, so I loaded it. You beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Now it's difficult to decide which answer to accept, the one which directly gives me a solution to my issue, or the one which actually answers my question with details?

Comment: @Jerry: Remy's contains the right information for you, and he beat me to it. It should be his. :-) I'll leave mine to provide the additional info for reference (or he can add it to his and I'll delete my answer).

Comment: Oh boy, now that I start implementing this, I realize for 53 string properties, I need *another* 53 functions, one for each :-) Cheers for long code!

Comment: Delphi 10.3 required: constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);

Comment: @JerryDodge too bad a `stored` method doesn't respect the `index` specifier, like the `read`/`write` methods do. Would be nice if a `stored` method could take an index as input, then you would need only 1 method with a large `case` statement.

Comment: Delphi 10.3 E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TMyComponent.SetProp'.  Fix would be: procedure TMyComponent.SetProp(const Value: String); begin if FProp <> Value then begin FProp := Value; end; end;

Comment: @ElDiablo happy now?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, I didn't catch it until I ran my own program working on something similar.  Also thanks for the answer to my question about negative default values!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. Assigning `default` to a property has two uses:

- To decide whether the property value is streamed to the DFM or not (used for ordinal or Boolean properties, usually, such as `Visible` - since the default would be `True`, there's no reason to write it to the DFM unless it's `False`. (See note below)
- For array properties, to indicate that the array is the default property of the class (such as Delphi's `TList.Items`, where having `Items` the default allows you to use `List[x]` instead of `List.Items[x]` in your code.

If your intent is to provide a default value to the string so it shows in the Object Inspector, simply set the value in the component constructor. If the user has assigned a different value, the value set in the constructor will be overwritten when the DFM content is streamed in.

As far as why string default values are not allowed, this is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Properties) (see "Storage Specifiers" (**emphasis mine**):

> The default and nodefault directives are **supported only for ordinal types and for set types**, provided the upper and lower bounds of the set's base type have ordinal values between 0 and 31; if such a property is declared without default or nodefault, it is treated as if nodefault were specified. **For reals, pointers, and strings, there is an implicit default value of 0, nil, and '' (the empty string), respectively.**

Note: The default is used in conjunction with the stored specifier that Remy's answer describes. From the same docs linked and quoted above (same section):

> When saving a component's state, the storage specifiers of the component's published properties are checked. **If a property's current value is different from its default value (or if there is no default value) and the stored specifier is True, then the property's value is saved. Otherwise, the property's value is not saved.**

Comment: My intent is to not save it to the DFM if it's the default, as this is designed to do. I'm finding it hard to believe that cannot be done with strings. But hey, there must be some technical reason why you can't do the same with strings.

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks. See my comment to Remy's answer (which appeared during my edit, just as I was about to start typing about `stored`). :-) He's just too fast sometimes.